# Creating authomatically inequalities/equations from a list of polynomials

Tags: list-manipulation, map, automation

I am trying to learn how to make automatically from a list of polynomials (or an arbitrary collection of algebraic expression) a list of inequalities/equalities (those will later serve as constraints in some optimization program).

So suppose I have the list like

```
polynoms={ax^2+bx+c, cx+d, a^3-20x+d}
```

and I would like to end up with a list like

```
const={ax^2+bx+c>=0, cx+d>=0, a^3-20x+d==0}
```

or at least with the list

```
const2={ax^2+bx+c>=0, cx+d>=0, a^3-20x+d>= 0}
```

where to the entire list the same $\geq 0$ has been applied. It is not a problem to do it manually when there are 3 or 5 inequalities to be generated, but when I have a list of 30 it becomse a nightmare... I have been searching through a bunch of possibilities how to do it automatically, but all are failing.. Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
polynoms = {ax^2 + bx + c, cx + d, a^3 - 20 x + d};

polynoms >= 0 // Thread

(*  {ax^2 + bx + c >= 0, cx + d >= 0, a^3 + d - 20 x >= 0}  *)

#[[1]][#[[2]], 0] & /@ Transpose[{
   {GreaterEqual, GreaterEqual, Equal},
   polynoms}]

(*  {ax^2 + bx + c >= 0, cx + d >= 0, a^3 + d - 20 x == 0}  *)
```

Or

```
Inner[#1[#2, 0] &,
 {GreaterEqual, GreaterEqual, Equal},
 polynoms, List]

(*  {ax^2 + bx + c >= 0, cx + d >= 0, a^3 + d - 20 x == 0}  *)
```

Comment: Thank you! It happened to be embarrassingly simple, I don't know how I failed to find "thread" command.

Answer (score 0):

First, you may need to separate ax and bx into `a * x` and `b * x` if they are products with 'x'

Depending on your subsequent application (for example `Solve`) you can `Apply` `Unequal` to the list so that each variable is unique

```
  equations={a*b,b*c}

  notequal =Apply[Unequal, {a,b,c}]
  equationsnotequal = Apply[Unequal,equations]
```

and pass desired constraints simply by adding the bounds on the list e.g

```
Solve[{a,b,c}>0 && notequal && equations<42 && equationsnotequal, {a,b,c}, Integers]
```

Comment: I need those constraints for NMaximize or FindFit, and those too sophisticated I guess to apply your idea...

Comment: OK, no worries.   Even though it doesn't address your specific use I think I will leave the answer here in case its useful for others, especially re `Solve`.  Was the comment about using a*x (or a_space_x) to represent the product of a and x in _Mathematica_ useful?